# Trying to remove user name from description column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Can someone please help with the below?

1. I am trying to remove firstname and lastname from the description column and trying to move them to new columns
2. The new description column should not contain firstname.lastname (it should contain only `DELL 2009xftp  DM0F532H7161888I793M NEW JERSEY`)
3. New columns: F_Name, L_Name, New_Description_without_FN_LN

Current sample data in the `description` column:

```
Firstname.Lastname DELL 2009xftp  DM0F532H7161888I793M NEW JERSEY
```

All 64k records have the same pattern like above.

Comment: What do you mean by a "field"? SQL Server has Rows and Columns. Do you mean a specific value in specific row and column in your table? Sample data and expected results will help us help you, along with your attempt(s) and an explanation of why they didn't work.

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask No one can help you if no one can understand you.

Answer (score 0):

if your data has the Firstname.Lastname and there are no spaces in the Firstname.Lastname then you can use `CHARINDEX()`, `LEN()` and `RIGHT()`

```
declare @var as varchar(50)
set @var = 'Firstname.Lastname DELL 2009xftp  DM0F532H7161888I793M NEW JERSEY'

select charindex(' ',@var)  --returns where the first space is; returns 19
select len(@var)            --returns the length of the string; returns 50
select right(@var,(len(@var)-charindex(' ',@var)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for replying back and appreciate your help.                                                   
 I have one question.            
 How do i implement the above for all 64k records.                                         
 set var = 'Firstname.Lastname DELL 2009xftp  DM0F532H7161888I793M NEW JERSEY'.                                                                                                                               I have different firstname, lastname and device name everytime.